# Attachments+Html generated with commons-email doesn't show in some email clients

Tags: java, email, html-email, apache-commons-email

I've been using the org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail class, from apache commons-mail, for some time. Eventually, some users complain that the email shows with no attachemnts on their e-mail client (problem reported in Outlook 2007 and Lotus Notes).

One user have even analysed the problem and sent me the following link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961940

I have read that others: have switched to raw javax.mail API due to this problem.

Here's the part of the code which attaches the files:

```
private void dummy(List<Map<String, byte[]>> attachments, String htmlText) throws EmailException {
    HtmlEmail memail;

    memail = new HtmlEmail();
    memail.setHtmlMsg(htmlText);
    memail.setTextMsg("Your mail client doesn't recognize HTML e-mails.");

    Iterator<Map<String, byte[]>> iter = attachments.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map<java.lang.String, byte[]> map = iter.next();

        Set<Entry<String, byte[]>> entries = map.entrySet();
        for (Entry<String, byte[]> entry : entries) {
            try {
                ByteArrayDataSource bads = new ByteArrayDataSource(
                        entry.getValue(), null);
                memail.embed(bads, entry.getKey());
//              memail.attach(bads, entry.getKey(), ""); // if I use this, the html message 
                        // gets displaced
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new EmailException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    // ... continues
}
```

Have anyone experienced that before?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Jonathas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there was a problem with commons-email version 1.1. Upgrading to 1.2 seems to solve the problem.